# Is there a data driven way to specify how to unravel data into groupings?

Tags: clojure, specter

Given many `event` datums that are all like:

```
{:a "a"
 :b [{:a "a2" :c "c2"} {:a "a3" :c "c3"}]
 :c "ignore"}
```

I want to count all the groupings by a user specified set of dimensions.

If I wanted the dimensions to be `:a` and the inner `:a` and `:c` values, then this datum contains the following groupings:

```
[["a" "a2" "c2"]
 ["a" "a3" "a3"]]
```

Note that `:b` contains a sequence which in turn needs to be destructured, so regular Clojure destructuring is not enough to get the result.

```
(let [{:keys [a b]} the-data]
  (for [{a2 :a, c2 :c} b]
    [a a2 c2]))
```

Produces the desired output in this case.

Is there a data driven way to express this? Some sort of query? Specter? Or some data structure that could be generically translated to let/for?

For example one way to represent it might be a pseudo destructuring:

```
{a :a
 [:a :c] :b}
```

And have some custom code to interpret it. This would allow safe user input of the dimensions to generate the groupings.

In short, what is a good way to specify such a "grouping" query with data?

Comment: Can you give another example of how the shape of the result could be different?  Could it be different for the same input?  You give some data, and then you produce "all the groupings" but it's not clear to me what criteria you are using to produce that result.  For example, would adding a `:d "d2"` and `:d "d3"` to the value of :b simply produce:

`[["a" "a2" "c2" "d2"] ["a" "a3" "c3" "d3"]]` ?

(also, note you left out the right brace on line 2 of your original data, and shouldn't the second vector in your output be `["a" "a3" "c3"]` ?

Comment: There are 2 inputs to the process: `some data` and `some grouping`, I've added some more detail to the question to try to make it clearer. Thanks :)